# Defining a function that modifies a list

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction

I have the a list `A` and I want to define a function `f` that takes out the $i$-th element from the list `A`:

```
A = {5, 2, 30, 14}

f[1] = 5;
f[2] = 2;
f[3] = 30;
```

I've tried `f[i_] = A[[i]]` but it didn't work.

Comment: But why do this when you can just do `A[[2]]`?

Comment: You are right, it is not necessary to define a function for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[i_] := A[[i]]
```

I think you would profit from learning the distinction between [immediate and delayed assignments](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).

Comment: Thanks Roman!! I am new at Mathematica.